# How does the validity and maximum allowed stay work for Chilean visas?

Tags: visas, chile, visa-expiration

I am an Indian passport holder going to visit Chile. I understand my visa validity is 90 days. My questions are:

- After entering Chile what is the maximum allowed duration of stay? Is it 30 days or more than that?
- How is the limit of stay enforced for multiple entry visas? Is it 30 days per stay or 30 days over a given time duration or 30 days from date of first entry?
- Say if I plan to take a day trip from Argentina to Chile and back on December 18, 2017. Again I enter Chile on December 28, 2017 and exit on January 23, 2018 (a stay of 27 days). I think my total stay in Chile will be 28 days (including the one-day trip). Considering the maximum allowed duration of stay, is such an itinerary within the visa rules?

Answer (score 1):

> After entering Chile what is the maximum allowed duration of stay? Is it 30 days or more than that?

If the visa states that it is valid *for a duration of 30 days* that means that the total number of days is 30, no more (counting from the day you enter to the day you leave). The entire clause may read *for a duration of 30 days to be used within 90 days of the date of issue"* and you could enter anytime within that 3-month date range.

> How is the limit of stay enforced for multiple entry visas? Is it 30 days per stay or 30 days over a given time duration or 30 days from date of first entry?

A multiple entry visa would indicate the terms, such as *multiple entry over a period of 90 days.* If there are no restrictions shown on the number of days for each visit, you could enter as frequently as you wish during the validity period, and stay as long as you want. If there is a limit on the days, it would apply to each visit, counted individually, not from date of first entry.

Your itinerary falls within the 30-day stay.